# Unable to submit form in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am not able to submit form in chrome extension.

When did i try to submit form, then whole page is refreshing instead of submit data and get the result.

Manifest.js:

```
{
    "name": "BrowserExtension",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description" : "Description ...",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png" ,
        "default_title": "That's the tool tip"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js", "background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js", "content.js"]
    }],
    "permissions": [
          "tabs", 
           "activeTab",    
           "https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/loginHome.jsf"
        ]
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
   if(changeInfo.status == 'complete')
   {

   if(tab.url === 'https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/mainpage.jsf')
   {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "js/autofillMain.js"});
   }

   }
});
```

Autofillmain.js:

```
   var userName = document.getElementById("jpform:fromStation");
    userName.value = "PUNE JN - PUNE";

    var password = document.getElementById("jpform:toStation");
    password.value = "GWALIOR - GWL";

    var date = document.getElementById("jpform:journeyDateInputDate");
    date.value = "30-08-2015";

    $("#jpform").submit();'
```

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: What does `background.js` have to do with the page in question? Please add your manifest and make sure you've read [this page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

Comment: background.js:

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
   if(changeInfo.status == 'complete')
   {
   if(tab.url === 'https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/mainpage.jsf')
   {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "js/autofillMain.js"});
   }
   }
});
 autofillmain.js: Code already mention as above.

I have tried to submit form lot of time but still i am not  able to get success. May be this question is silly, but I have already spent 24 hours then i posted on stackoverflow.

Comment: Please learn how to use Stack Overflow as well. Code is unreadable in comments, you should edit your question instead.

Comment: @Xan, 
In the comment section, I am not able to indent my code. 

I have only one option, I have to delete this question and  add new question with all information i.e. background.js, manifest.js, autofillmain.js (indent format).
"If you have any other option please let me know, I will do it because I have to complete this task with in 2 days."

Comment: There's an "edit" button under your question.

Comment: I have edited my old post. Please check and let me know where I was wrong. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: That's better, but the issue is almost impossible to diagnose without inspecting the DOM of the page you're trying to manipulate, and it's behind a login. I don't think we can help.

Comment: There are different different extension available in the chrome market for auto-fill irctc form i.e. easytatkal, magicautofill.
I want to create my own extension and I have created all most apart from this functionality, If you can help me please let me know how can solve this problem.

Comment: 1. Try calling the submit button's `click()`, maybe that site relies on it and has a malformed form 2. Add `#jpform` html to the question or at least its action url.

Comment: Thanks you so much @wOxxOm. I got solution.

Comment: I was using  "$("#jpform").submit();" for submit the form.
on that time data was not submit on page, only refreshing the whole page.
but now I am 
using " document.getElementById("jpform:jpsubmit").click();". 
it is working fine.

Comment: Okay, I've added the answer, so it would make more sense if you accept it as a solution, delete your last comment here and add it under the answer where it'll be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

That site's form probably relies on the submit button being clicked to run some necessary code in the click handler.

Try calling the submit button's click() explicitly, something like this:

- via jQuery: `$("#jpform [type='submit']:not([disabled])").click()`
- via standard js: `document.querySelector("#jpform [type='submit']:not([disabled])").click()`